# MYSQL Select statment Order By with Group By

Tags: sql, mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following simple SQL statment

```
SELECT id, name, value_name, value_id
FROM table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY value_id DESC
```

when grouping I would like to get the value_name and value_id of the tuple where the value_id is the biggest. The way it is i am getting the smallest value. For example

```
1, name1, valuename, 3     (where i know that there is a value_id of 5)
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `, value_id` to `, MAX(value_id) AS value_id` in the field list...

Actually, now that I look at it, I think what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, MAX(b.value_id) AS value_id, (SELECT b.value_name FROM table AS b WHERE b.id = a.id AND b.value_id = MAX(a.value_id)) AS value_name
FROM table AS a 
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY value_id DESC
```

The problem is that the table isn't fully normalized.  So you have multiple rows with id and name being the same, but each has a unique value_id and value_name.  So the only ways to get the value_name associated with the value_id is either through a subquery (what I did there), or a join...

Comment: You will need to group by the other non-aggregate fields.

Comment: @irchmaxell He will still need to add name and value_name to his group by clause.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that he was asking for the value_name associated with the MAX(value_id).  Edited answer to correspond...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, value_name, MAX(value_id )
FROM table 
GROUP BY id, name, value_name
ORDER BY value_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

-- MySQL

```sql
select
 city, length(city) 
from station  
group by city 
having length(city)=(select min(length(city)) from station) order by city ASC limit 1;

select
 city, length(city) 
from station group by city having length(city)=(select max(length(city)) from station)
limit 1;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can get biggest value_id by this statement:

```
SELECT id, name, value_name, value_id
FROM table
GROUP BY value_id 
HAVING max(value_id)
```

If you want to get other columns you can using a sub query with it.